# Centred header on desktop but full screen width header on mobile devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a simple Bootstrap 3 site within a container, so the whole content is centred with auto margins left and right.

On mobile devices i need the header to take the full width of the screen for the background color but the content of the header (logo, navigation) need to be vertically aligned with everything else, like page content.

My structure is:

```
.container
    header.row
        .logo.col-md-8
        .navigation.col-md-8
    /header.row
    .row
        .content.col-md-16
    /.row
    ...
/.container
```

Comment: Add the class col-xs-12 to your header

Comment: im not sure what the expected output should look like, but this sounds like a case for `.container-fluid` and `.col-md-12`?

Comment: .container-fluid is what i need for mobile but it is 100% width of screen on desktop too. But on desktop i want the centred .container. I guess i need to set the width of my header manually for every breakpoint to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want header to be full width then you will have to move it out of container class and apply a custom class that will center it for larger screens and will be 100% on smaller screen. Use media query for that.